# Photoshop CS6 GIF not showing transition

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, gif

Ive made a `GIF` image in **Photoshop CS6**.

The `gif` is made up of three pictures that a fade animation.

This works fine when i run the gif within photoshop (the actual program) but when i save for web the transitions don't show, it simply just changes the images (with no transition).

**Does anyone know why this is happening and what i can do to get the wanted effect?**

Please tell me if you need more information

Comment: Perhaps you don't have enough frames in your timeline to accommodate the fade? How do you have your frames set up on your Animation menu?

Comment: Do you have `Transparency` checked in your GIF settings in the `Save for Web` window? Here is a link that has a solution to a similar problem: http://www.stoneleighphotography.com/making-a-gif-in-cs6-photoshop/

Comment: I have the same problem: 3 pics, cross fade, in Photoshop everything's fine, in GIF or HTML -- no transition.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser or application you try to preview the gif file? Every browser has its frame rate for animated gifs. For example if you give a frame rate under 0.6 ms delay to a frame, IE automatically round this 0.10. And this will make your gif faster and you could not see the transition. Try test in another browser and changing your frame rate.